# Can not run Wifi and Bluetooth scans in background with Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth, background, wifi

I am working on a part of an indoor localization project. I need my Flutter application scan and get Mac addresses and RSSI values of Wifi and Bluetooth devices. I am using [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) for bluetooth scans and [wifi_scan](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_scan) for Wifi scans. The application works well while in the foreground but scans are failing when the application is in background.

What I have tried so far:

- Tried to change Bluetooth scan mode from `ScanMode.lowLatency` to `ScanMode.lowPower` and `ScanMode.opportunistic` for the `startScan()` method for [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue).
- [flutter_background](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background). I managed to do some tasks in background but wifi and bluetooth did not work.
- [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) the same situation
- [flutter_foreground_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_plugin) the same situation
- [flutter_foreground_task](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task) the same situation
- [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) did not try it because it says it can trigger the bg operation per every 15 minutes but I am scanning per every 6 seconds.

Is there any way to achieve this? Aren't there any package with the option `backgroundMode: true`? I don't know the natives. Don't know Kotlin too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of things have been tried, I just tried to get GPS location too.

Used this package: [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location)

And execute `location.enableBackgroundMode(enable: true)` as it is stated in readme, then my wifi and bluetooth scans starts working in background too.

It's Ridicoulus

Comment: Hi, I struggle for a few days to get this working.
I use on Android 11 and 13:
`flutter_blue_plus: ^1.3.1`
`flutter_foreground_task: ^3.10.0`

I have all the permissions in the manifest file and it is working while the screen is on.
Have you a working example to provide, I would appreciate it a lot.
I cannot get `location` to work in foreground task too.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings#SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER),  `ScanMode.lowPower` is the only possible mode for background scanning. You also need to request location access for the background (documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/find-bluetooth-devices)).

Consider switching to [Flutter Blue Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus) instead of Flutter Blue; Flutter Blue Plus is the currently-maintained version. [This pull request](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/pull/191) on GitHub shows that Flutter Blue cannot run in the background. The pull request has never been merged.

Comment: I've tried it before but maybe there was something that I've missed. So I'll give it another try, thanks